# Can we have a local git repository with a remote working tree accessible only through FTP?

Tags: git

I haven't found anything on this yet. The only way I know this is possible is by setting up a net drive (e.g. netdrive.net or something similar) with a repo on it that we can tell our local bare repo to use as a working tree. It won't have any idea the content is actually going to some place across the net.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I don't think Git will ever support such a setup. But why would you want to do it?

Comment: The reason is because a web server I'm working with only has FTP access. (it has SSH, but not git). If I could do this, I can run all the git commands locally, while the remote location gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: no.  Reason: git needs easy access to `.git/index` and `lstat()` system calls.  You probably don't want the index on the remote location either, so why not just have your post-receive hook (in your `--bare` repo where you put "final deploy" versions) update a non-bare repo somewhere, then ftp over the changed files?  (You can get a list of "just the added / changed / removed files" with `git diff-tree -r` as long as you know which version is currently live on the remote web server.)